# While configuring BPS DB in wso2 is 5.9.0 , which scripts do i have to import in MySQL?

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-identity-server, wso2-esb

I am following this document-https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.9.0/setup/changing-datasource-bpsds/

```
deployment.toml Configurations.


[bps_database.config]
url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/IAMtest?useSSL=false"
username = "root"
password = "root"
driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
Executing database scripts.

Navigate to <IS-HOME>/dbscripts. Execute the scripts in the following files, against the database created.

<IS-HOME>/dbscripts/bps/bpel/create/mysql.sql
<IS-HOME>/dbscripts/bps/bpel/drop/mysql-drop.sql
<IS-HOME>/dbscripts/bps/bpel/truncate/mysql-truncate.sql
```

Now create/mysql.sql creates table and the rest two file are responsible for deleting and trucating the same table..............what do i do?????????

Can anyone also tell the use case of BPS datasource??????

Please Help...........

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should only change your bps database if you have a requirement of using the workflow feature[1] in the wso2 identity server. It is mentioned in this documentation https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.9.0/setup/changing-to-mysql/

The document supposed to menstion the related db script. But it seems like mis leading. As it has requested to execute all three scripts. if you are using the workflow feature just use the 
/dbscripts/bps/bpel/create/mysql.sql 
script to create tables in you mysql database.

[1]. https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.9.0/learn/workflow-management/

Comment: Thank you @AmanPrakash for reporting it. We have fixed this documentation issue with https://github.com/wso2/docs-is/issues/942